# Which one is correct, "有名" or "受欢迎" for translating "comics are so popular in Japan"?

Tags: translation

I want to say

> comics are so popular in Japan.

According to Google Translate, the word "popular" doesn't translate to Chinese as "有名". It translates as "受欢迎" I am confused about which one is correct.

> 漫画在日本很有名。

OR

> 漫画在日本如此受欢迎

Comment: this appears to be a dictionary question, easily answered by iciba, for one, at the entry for "popular" find 1. ADJ-GRADED 受喜爱的；受欢迎的；当红的 Something that is popular is enjoyed or liked by a lot of people.

Comment: I would hesitate to use Google Translate as a definitive source of reference... the answers to your question suggests that 流行 is the most accurate translation if you want to say that comics are popular in the sense that it is a favourite pastime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it should be "受欢迎".

"有名" means famous, well-known.

Answer (score 3):

- 「`有名`」是指很多人都知道他/她/它的名字，但不一定喜欢他/她/它。
- 「`受欢迎`」是指有人喜欢他/她/它，对于他/她/它的到来感到高兴。

你的两个翻译都不是特别确切。我认为比较好的是

> 漫画在日本很流行。

流行的意思是目前已经有很多人喜欢他/她/它了，而且越来越多的人开始喜欢他/她/它。不仅突出了现在，还强调了趋势。

Answer (score 2):

The word "popular" has a few meanings in English.  So it really depends on the context how you translate this word to Chinese.

For example, if John is the most popular English teacher in the training center, he is "最受欢迎的英语老师".

Another example, if some music is popular and **you need to emphasize** it is for ordinary people other than professionals, the music is "通俗音乐".

Sorry I know I'm not answering your question but hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should use 流行
漫画在日本很流行。

流行 - most people like that and easy to understanding or do it, usually it be used to describe the behavior or things ...

有名 - most people know that, not sure like that, usually it be use to describe someone, event or place ...

受欢迎 - most people like that.

Hope useful for understanding ... :)